# Exclude permissions from Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Apparently when calling FB.login, the default permissions the user will have to give is this:
"xxx will receive the following info: your public profile and friend list".

And I know that I can add extra permissions with: { scope : 'email' } and so on.
The problem is, I don't want the whole public profile and the friend list.

The only thing I want is: first name, last name and email.
Is it possible to exclude the basic permissions and just have the ones I want?

Comment: No, not possible. Discussed here multiple times before already.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you put this in a answer and maybe add a source I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/:

*“When someone connects with an app using Facebook Login, the app can access their public profile and friend list, the pieces of information that are visible to everyone. ”*

Comment: Thanks.. This sucks though.. How hard would it be for FB to make it possible to remove all permissions and add only those needed. It can scare users away when I want their list of friends.

Comment: Well, Facebook sees the “social” aspect of using apps as a top priority – so they think it’s important for most apps to be able to access a user’s friend list, to maybe deliver content based on what their friends like or did in an app, etc. That’s how the system works.

Comment: It does suck. I myself have aborted the authorization hundreds of times at the last step when I see some random app will have access to my friends list. It's the app's and Facebook's loss.

Comment: *When someone connects with an app using Facebook Login, the app can access their public profile and friend list, the pieces of information that are **visible to everyone**.* I thought some of these 'pieces' (i.e., friends list) are **not visible to everyone**. Am I missing something here or is it just poor documentation?